# How to Create BottomNavigator in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, bottomnavigationview

I'd like to create a BottomNavigator in React Native. But I have this  error :Creating a navigator doesn't take an argument. Maybe you are trying to use React Navigation 4 API with React Navigation 5?". I tried many times for searching a solution, but I always have this error. I know that I used deprecated syntax but I can't find how to do it... Thanks for your help guys.

```
import React from 'react'
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'

import Search from '../Components/Search'
import FilmDetail from '../Components/FilmDetail'
import Favorites from '../Components/Favorites'

const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Rechercher'
    }
  },
  FilmDetail: {
    screen: FilmDetail
  }
})

const MoviesTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Search: {
      screen: SearchStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: () => { 
          return <Image
            source={require('../Images/ic_search.png')}
            style={styles.icon}/> 
        }
      }
    },
    Favorites: {
      screen: Favorites,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: () => {
          return <Image
            source={require('../Images/ic_favorite.png')}
            style={styles.icon}/>
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeBackgroundColor: '#DDDDDD', 
      inactiveBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', 
      showLabel: false, 
      showIcon: true 
    }
  }
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30
  }
})

export default createAppContainer(MoviesTabNavigator)
```

Comment: Try to use v5 it's pretty nice

Comment: I tried but Iam starting to learn React-native and I don't understand the new syntax...